# Form does not size correctly

Tags: macos, swiftui

Form does not appear to size correctly. What am I doing wrong?

View with Form commented out:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var name = ""
    @State var subject = ""
    @State var suggesion = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Form Sizing Demo")
           // Form {
                TextField("Name ", text: $name)
                TextField("Subject ", text: $subject)
                LabeledContent("Suggestion") {
                    TextEditor(text: $suggesion)
                        .frame(minWidth: 300, minHeight: 250)
                }
                Text("ID: \(UUID())")
                    .font(.system(.body, design: .serif))
                HStack {
                    Button("Save") {
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button( "Dismiss", role: .destructive) {
                    }
                }
            }
      //  }
      }
}
```

[image: Screen Shot]

With Form:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var name = ""
    @State var subject = ""
    @State var suggesion = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Form Sizing Demo")
            Form {
                TextField("Name ", text: $name)
                TextField("Subject ", text: $subject)
                LabeledContent("Suggestion") {
                    TextEditor(text: $suggesion)
                        .frame(minWidth: 300, minHeight: 250)
                }
                Text("ID: \(UUID())")
                    .font(.system(.body, design: .serif))
                HStack {
                    Button("Save") {
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button( "Dismiss", role: .destructive) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot, window pulled down to reveal as much as will appear:]

Specifying minHeight for either the Form or the Stack does not seem to make a difference. Clearly, I'm missing something.

Also, notice that the label added to TextEditor doesn't align as you might expect. (That can be fixed with .offset, but these issues suggest there's something I'm missing and would like to understand.)

Answer (score 0):

Including the labels within the `TextField` would require creating a `VStack` within itself. To align the "Suggestion" form neatly underneath the textfields you'll want exclude it from the textfields  `VStack` and adjust the padding accordingly.

```
// quick way of adding newlines to a string

    func newLines(_ count: Int) -> String {
        return String(repeating: "\n", count: count)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
        VStack {
            Text("Form Sizing Demo").padding(.top, 12)
                VStack { ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    if name.isEmpty {
                        Text("Name")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .font(.caption).padding(.leading, 16)
                    }
                    TextField("", text: $name)
                        .font(.caption)
                }
                    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        if subject.isEmpty {
                            Text("Subject")
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                .font(.caption).padding(.leading, 16)
                        }
                        TextField("", text: $subject)
                            .font(.caption)
                    }
                }.padding(.trailing, 8)
         
                LabeledContent("\(newLines(12))Suggestion") {
                        TextEditor(text: $suggesion)
                            .frame(minWidth: 300, minHeight: 250)
                }
                .padding(.top, -8)
                .padding(.leading, 8)
                .padding(.trailing, 8)
                .font(.caption)
            
                Text("ID: \(UUID())")
                    .font(.caption)
                HStack {
                    Button("Save") {
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button( "Dismiss", role: .destructive) {
                    }
                }
                .padding(.leading, 8)
                .padding(.trailing, 8)
                .padding(.bottom, 22)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: swiftui form]

This example can definitely be improved, and you'll likely want to play around with the padding and stacking of things as you see fit, although this should give you some idea of how to rearrange form elements.